# Windows Authentication not working with IIS - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, windows-authentication

I have silverlight app which works fine when runs on Cassini, its just on IIS windows authentication doesnt work. Following are the steps I have taken so far.
Added following node in web.config

```
 <identity impersonate="true" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>

<profile enabled="false"/>
```

Enabled Windows authentication method in IIS.

But doesnt seems to help. I am get empty User object.
But again same code works fine with visual studio's local server/. Please help;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make use of elevated permission through code. and bingo it worked just fine.

```
 using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) // this line did the magic.
        {//rest of my code. }
```